# log4j2.properties Elastic cluster logs rolling and compressed issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have configured a 4-node elastic Cluster on CentOS7 ,Elasticsearch-75.2 and  using default Log4j2.properties for rolling and compressing the logs files on a daily basis .

But the problem is only Master1 Node will rolling  and compressed .gz the log files,  the rest of the nodes i.e. Master2,Hotnode and warm node are not compressed log files on a daily bases.

Please suggest me on this.

```
Examples:
Master1
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch    69912 Jun 19 00:00 DevElasticStack-2021-06-18-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch    74597 Jun 19 00:00 DevElasticStack-2021-06-18-1.json.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch    77119 Jun 20 00:00 DevElasticStack-2021-06-19-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch    81060 Jun 20 00:00 DevElasticStack-2021-06-19-1.json.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch    77353 Jun 21 00:00 DevElasticStack-2021-06-20-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch    81333 Jun 21 00:00 DevElasticStack-2021-06-20-1.json.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch  2586115 Jun 21 06:53 DevElasticStack_server.json
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch  2414714 Jun 21 06:53 DevElasticStack.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 50078914 Jun 21 06:54 gc.log

 Other nodes:ie. hotnode:

-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 67108985 Jun 21 09:10 gc.log.01
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 2616 Jun 21 09:10 DevElasticStack-2021-06-18-1.json.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 2472 Jun 21 09:10 DevElasticStack-2021-06-18-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 31011 Jun 21 09:10 gc.log.02
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 1479 Jun 21 09:10 gc.log.03
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 42182 Jun 21 09:10 DevElasticStack_server.json
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 31628 Jun 21 09:10 DevElasticStack.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 elk elasticsearch 10053435 Jun 21 15:10 gc.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit log4j.properties file on all the nodes and restart cluster.